# Why does this not print the numbers in ascending order

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,sum=0,n;
    int a[10];
    float avg;
        cout<<"Enter how many numbers you want ";
        cin>>n;
        if (n>10)
        n=10;
            cout<<"Enter the numbers" << endl;
                for (i=0;i<n;i++)
                    cin>>a[i];
                for (i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        sum=sum+a[i];
                    }
                        avg=sum/n;
        cout<<"sum of array elements "<<sum << endl;
        cout<<"average of array elements " <<avg << endl;

int temp;
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;  
            }
        }
    }
cout << "The numbers in ascending order are:" << endl;

for (int i =0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

when I run this program the numbers print out in a different order.

if I use the numbers 1 2 3 4 5.  they print out as 1 5 4 3 2.

everything else runs fine.  How to fix this error?

Comment: Your sort algorithm is incorrect. What happens if, for example, you compare elements `a[4]` and `a[1]`?

Comment: how can i make it so that it compares all the numbers?

Comment: This some kind of strange insertion sort not working correctly, you could easily transform it to a bubble sort

Answer (score 2):

Your sort implementation is incorrect. Since the idea of the sort is to find `i`-th smallest number at each step, the inner loop should start at `i+1`, not at `1`:

```
for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qdjbHM)